# значение типа int нельзя присвоить значению типа int*

Tags: c

Задача:Характеристикой столбца целочисленной матрицы назовем сумму модулей его отрицательных
нечетных элементов. Переставляя столбцы заданной матрицы, расположить их в соответствии с
ростом характеристик. Я сделал, но в моменте приравнивая int *temp к массиву, пишет ошибку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать. Сам код:

```
int** mas = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
     for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mas[i][j]);


    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        printf("%5d ", mas[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        if ((mas[i][j] < 0) && (mas[i][j] % 2 != 0))

        {
            sum1 += mas[i][j] * (-1);
        }
        if (mas[i + 1][j] < 0 && mas[i + 1][j] % 2 != 0)
        {
            sum2 += mas[i + 1][j] * (-1);
        }
    }
    if (sum1 > sum2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            int* tmp = mas[i][j];
            mas[i][j] = mas[i + 1][j];
            mas[i + 1][j] = *tmp;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        printf("%5d ", mas[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Просто `int tmp`, `= tmp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ошибка выделяете количество памяти под размер чисел, а надо под указатели.

```
int** mas = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof( int   ));
                                    // -- v --
int** mas = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof( int * ));
```

Вторая - ошибка компилятора несоответстия типов. Элемент массива имеет тип числа, а вы присваиваете указателю.

```
  int * tmp = mas[i][j];
// -- v --
  int   tmp = mas[i][j];

mas[i + 1][j] = * tmp;
          // -- v --
mas[i + 1][j] =   tmp;
```

Третья логическая. Выделяете память на строки под количество столбцов и наоборот.

```
int** mas = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int * ));  // M -> N
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // M -> N
{
    mas[i] = (int*)malloc(M * sizeof(int)); // N -> M
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // N -> M
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) // N -> M
    {
        printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &mas[i][j]);
    }
}
```